# Leiningen: unable to use "insecure" proxy repository

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am running a Nexus repository in my local network that I am trying to get Leiningen (2.8.1) to use. However I'm running into the issue where Leiningen refuses to connect over non-HTTPS connections.

My profiles.clj looks something like this:

```
{:user
 {
  :mirrors {#".+" {:name "superbia"
                   :url "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public"}}
  }
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
% lein
Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS.
This is almost certainly a mistake; however in rare cases where it's
intentional please see `lein help faq` for details.
```

When looking at that FAQ entry it tells me to add stuff to my project.clj, which I can't, since it refuses to do basically anything, let alone create a project.

Even requesting the version breaks:

```
% lein -v
Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS.
This is almost certainly a mistake; however in rare cases where it's
intentional please see `lein help faq` for details.
```

Is there any way to disable or bypass this behaviour without either downgrading Leiningen (which is what I did last time) or reconfiguring the proxy repository?

Comment: You may wish to ask this question on the Clojure mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/clojure

Comment: do you have docker installed? If so I'll suggest ways to use it to fix this, otherwise I'll keep looking

Comment: How about removing the offending URL from your profile first, then create the project (I assume that you want to use `lein new`), finally re-add the the offending URL and the HTTP workaround?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt one of the machines involved does, the other one does not

Comment: @Svante that could be a workaround, however, then I'd have to muck about with proxy settings and the like. I'd prefer a structural solution.

Comment: @AlanThompson I had hoped someone would have found a workable solution by now. I hadn't considered using the Clojure ML though, thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: [the leiningen FAQ](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md)

> Q: I got Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS, what is
>   that about? A: This means your project was configured to download
>   dependencies from a repository that does not use TLS encryption. This
>   is very insecure and exposes you to trivially-executed
>   man-in-the-middle attacks. In the rare event that you don't care about
>   the security of the machines running your project or can ensure that
>   the only http traffic is going out over a trusted network, you can
>   re-enable support for unsafe repositories by putting this in your
>   project.clj file:
>
> ```
> ;; never do this (require 'cemerick.pomegranate.aether)
> (cemerick.pomegranate.aether/register-wagon-factory!  "http"
> #(org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon.))
> ```
>
> It's also possible you have a dependency which includes a reference to an
>   insecure repository for retrieving its own dependencies. If this
>   happens it is strongly recommended to add an :exclusion and report a
>   bug with the dependency which does this.

You can always edit `project.clj` regardless of `lein` running or not - just use your favorite editor to edit the file. There is also a per-user `$HOME./lein/profiles.clj` - you can add the lines above in this file.

Alternatively you can downgrade lein (to ex. 2.7.1), either:

- `lein upgrade 2.7.1`
- edit `˜/bin/lein` at the top, you should see `export LEIN_VERSION="2.7.1`"

Comment: In the question I explicitly address the FAQ and why it's not applicable, I also state my desire of not having to downgrade after having done so in the past.

Comment: @BertGeens in your question you say this is not applicable, however you do not need lein to edit a file. Edit either your `project.clj` or `profiles.clj` to add the lines mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea where in my $HOME/.lein/profiles.clj to add that.  Just adding it to the top level results in a ClassCastException when I start Leiningen, which isn't entirely unexpected as that file, from what I can tell, is supposed to contain a map.